# Importing Webform Submission List (Text) with Feeds Tamper

Tags: webforms, feeds

I am exporting Webform Submissions from one Drupal site and attempting to import them onto another site with Feeds.

Unfortunately, the "Select Options" Webform field (that allows for multiple options to be selected) looks like the following in the exported file.

[image]

I am attempting to import these results directly into Drupal with feeds. I wish for these to go into one List (Text) field called "Status Desired".

As you can see, these all have different headers and I want them all to go into the same field.

[image]

I tried to use the "Find replace" in Feeds Tamper to change the "X" to the correct value but I had no success.

For example, if the user selects all 4 of the options, only the last one is imported.

[image]

Is there any way for me to use Feeds Tamper to import this as is into Drupal?

Or will I have no choice but to modify the data in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution on [thejibe](https://thejibe.com/articles/feeds-importing-multiple-values-one-multi-value-field).

The Feeds Tamper setting I was looking for was "Rewrite".

[image]

In the last field, I added "Rewrite" and added tokens for each of the values separated by commas.

[image]

Following that, I added Explode.

I did a test import and had great success.

I hope this helps someone.

[image]